# attachInterrupt has no effect on Industruino SAMD21

Tags: interrupt, samd21g

I'm using Industruino D21G (SAMD21G version) with Visual Studio Code extension for Arduino. `attachInterrupt` seems to have no effect. I tried Industruino CH1, CH6 and CH7 with the same result. When I poll these channels in a loop, I detect signal level change as expected. Here is the code:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <Indio.h>  

constexpr int PROXIMITY_SENSOR_NC = 6;

void setup() {
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
  Indio.digitalMode(PROXIMITY_SENSOR_NC, INPUT);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(PROXIMITY_SENSOR_NC), blink, FALLING);    
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
}


void blink() {
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, !digitalRead(LED_BUILTIN));              
}


void loop() {
}
```

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145801/discussion-on-question-by-paul-jurczak-attachinterrupt-has-no-effect-on-industru); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Industrial level I/O on Industruino, which includes CH1, CH6 and CH7 I tried, is not connected directly to the microcontroller. It uses a buffer and communicates through I2C in pull mode. That's why interrupt on I/O change has no effect.